# Awk function, syntax error near unexpected 'myArr,'

Tags: shell, awk, array, function

I am not sure why my simple function causes "Syntax error near unexpected 'myArr,'. I taking an array, lookup key value and a line item section name as arguments. Each row in the array is "," delimited string. I am checking if the first string equals the look key value. If it does I will print out the row to my output file. I am using awk. I have the function outside of the awk being script.

```
Authorization="Authorization.csv";
LineItem="LineItem.csv";
ModifierCode="ModifierCode.csv";

OUTFILE="output.csv"
function LineItems(myArr, AuthKey, LIsection){
        for (LI in myArr)
        {

        split(myArr[LI], a, ",")
        if (a[1] == AuthKey) 
        {
        print LIsection"," myArr[LI] > "output.csv"
        }
    }
}


awk 'BEGIN  { NR>1
 while (getline < "'"$Authorization"'" )
{
        split($0,ft,",");

        Auth_num=ft[4];
        request_date=ft[5];
        status=ft[8];
        state=ft[9];
        state_date=ft[10];
        request_source=ft[12];
        method=ft[13];
        level_of_urgency=ft[17];
        urgency_requested_by=ft[18];
        primary_diagnosis=ft[19];
        primary_code=ft[20];
        continuity_of_care=ft[21];
        court_ordered=ft[22];
        member_eligibility_and_benifits_verified=ft[23];
        single_case_agreement=ft[24];
        case_name=ft[25];
        requesting_provider=ft[28];
        requesting_provider_id=ft[29];
        requesting_provider_npi=ft[30];
        requesting_provider_phone=ft[32];
        requesting_provider_phone_ext=ft[34];
        requesting_provider_fax_number=ft[36];

        Authorization_Arr[Auth_num]=Auth_num","request_date","status","state","state_date","request_source","method","level_of_urgency","urgency_requested_by","primary_diagnosis","primary_code","continuity_of_care","court_ordered","member_eligibility_and_benifits_verified","single_case_agreement","case_name","requesting_provider","requesting_provider_id","requesting_provider_npi","requesting_provider_phone","requesting_provider_phone_ext","requesting_provider_fax_number;

}
    close("'"$Authorization"'");

    LineItCounter=0;
    while (getline < "'"$LineItem"'")
    {

        split($0,li,",");
        LineItCounter=LineItCounter+1
        LI_Auth_num=li[4];
        LI_ID=li[5];            
        line_item_number=li[6];
        requested_from_date=li[7];
        requested_to_date=li[8];
        type=li[9];
        requested_date=li[10];
        determination_due_date=li[12];
        service_type=li[13];
        status=li[14];
        level_of_urgency=li[15];
        urgency_requested_by=li[16];
        primary_procedure=li[18];
        code=li[19];
        applied_eligibility=li[20];
        servicing_provider=li[21];
        provider_id=li[22];
        npi=li[23];
        in_network=li[24];
        servicing_provider_phone=li[26];
        place_of_service=li[28];
        comments=li[29];
        method=li[30];
        out_of_network_reason=li[31];
        preliminary_requested_units=li[33];
        request_source=li[34];
        determined_from_date=li[35];
        determined_to_date=li[36];
        determination=li[37];
        requested_units=li[39];
        recommended_units=li[40];
        determined_units=li[41];
        type_of_decision=li[42];

        LineItem_Arr[LI_ID]=LI_Auth_num","LI_ID","line_item_number","requested_from_date","type","requested_date","determination_due_date","service_type","status","level_of_urgency","urgency_requested_by","primary_procedure","code","applied_eligibility","servicing_provider","provider_id","npi","in_network","servicing_provider_phone","place_of_service","comments","method","out_of_network_reason","preliminary_requested_units","request_source","determined_from_date","determined_to_date","determination","requested_units","recommended_units","determined_units","type_of_decision;    

    }
        close("'"$LineItem"'");

    Modcounter=0;
    while (getline < "'"$ModifierCode"'")
    {

        split($0,mi,",");
        Modcounter=Modcounter+1
        Mod_Auth_num=mi[4];
        Modifier_ID=mi[5];
        modifier_code=mi[7];

        ModifierCode_Arr[Modcounter]=Mod_Auth_num","Modifier_ID","modifier_code;

    }
        close("'"$ModifierCode"'");


         for (key in Authorization_Arr)
         {   
            if (key != "authorization_num") 
            { 
                print "SASH," Authorization_Arr[key] > "output.csv" 

                LineItems(LineItem_Arr,key"SPLI")
                LineItems(ModifierCode_Arr,key,"SPLI_Mod")

            }
        }       








}'
```

Comment: Put the awk code inside the quoted argument passed to `awk` and try again. No, I didn't review your stuff -- it's just that that error is from bash, not from awk.

Comment: do you mean put the function within the awk code? I am not sure you mean  uncle billy.

Comment: of course, it's `awk`, not `bash` code. Paste it after the single quote, just before the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: [Shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) don't use parameters in it's declarations.

Comment: Why do you have a `while...` loop inside your `BEGIN` clause? That really makes little sense. The `BEGIN` clause is to set up variables, etc., before the main `awk` loop runs across its input.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer -- except for moving the awk function into the awk code. More of a suggestion: I'd lay that code out like this, in a more idiomatic awk style:

```c
awk -v authFile="$Authorization" \
    -v lineFile="$LineItem" \
    -v modFile="$ModifierCode" \
    -v output="$OUTFILE" \
'
    BEGIN  {
        # build the file list dynamically
        ARGV[ARGC++] = authFile
        ARGV[ARGC++] = lineFile
        ARGV[ARGC++] = modFile
    }

    function LineItems(myArr, AuthKey, LIsection) {
        for (LI in myArr) { 
            split(myArr[LI], a, ",")
            if (a[1] == AuthKey) {
                print LIsection"," myArr[LI] > output
            }
        }
    }

    FILENAME == authFile {
        split($0,ft,",")

        Auth_num = ft[4]
        request_date = ft[5]
        status = ft[8]
        state = ft[9]
        state_date = ft[10]
        request_source = ft[12]
        method = ft[13]
        level_of_urgency = ft[17]
        urgency_requested_by = ft[18]
        primary_diagnosis = ft[19]
        primary_code = ft[20]
        continuity_of_care = ft[21]
        court_ordered = ft[22]
        member_eligibility_and_benifits_verified = ft[23]
        single_case_agreement = ft[24]
        case_name = ft[25]
        requesting_provider = ft[28]
        requesting_provider_id = ft[29]
        requesting_provider_npi = ft[30]
        requesting_provider_phone = ft[32]
        requesting_provider_phone_ext = ft[34]
        requesting_provider_fax_number = ft[36]

        Authorization_Arr[Auth_num] = Auth_num","request_date","status","state","state_date","request_source","method","level_of_urgency","urgency_requested_by","primary_diagnosis","primary_code","continuity_of_care","court_ordered","member_eligibility_and_benifits_verified","single_case_agreement","case_name","requesting_provider","requesting_provider_id","requesting_provider_npi","requesting_provider_phone","requesting_provider_phone_ext","requesting_provider_fax_number
    }

    FILENAME == lineFile {
        split($0,li,",")

        LI_Auth_num = li[4]
        LI_ID = li[5]
        line_item_number = li[6]
        requested_from_date = li[7]
        requested_to_date = li[8]
        type = li[9]
        requested_date = li[10]
        determination_due_date = li[12]
        service_type = li[13]
        status = li[14]
        level_of_urgency = li[15]
        urgency_requested_by = li[16]
        primary_procedure = li[18]
        code = li[19]
        applied_eligibility = li[20]
        servicing_provider = li[21]
        provider_id = li[22]
        npi = li[23]
        in_network = li[24]
        servicing_provider_phone = li[26]
        place_of_service = li[28]
        comments = li[29]
        method = li[30]
        out_of_network_reason = li[31]
        preliminary_requested_units = li[33]
        request_source = li[34]
        determined_from_date = li[35]
        determined_to_date = li[36]
        determination = li[37]
        requested_units = li[39]
        recommended_units = li[40]
        determined_units = li[41]
        type_of_decision = li[42]

        LineItem_Arr[LI_ID] = LI_Auth_num","LI_ID","line_item_number","requested_from_date","type","requested_date","determination_due_date","service_type","status","level_of_urgency","urgency_requested_by","primary_procedure","code","applied_eligibility","servicing_provider","provider_id","npi","in_network","servicing_provider_phone","place_of_service","comments","method","out_of_network_reason","preliminary_requested_units","request_source","determined_from_date","determined_to_date","determination","requested_units","recommended_units","determined_units","type_of_decision
    }

    FILENAME == modFile { 
        split($0,mi,",")

        Mod_Auth_num = mi[4]
        Modifier_ID = mi[5]
        modifier_code = mi[7]

        ModifierCode_Arr[FNR] = Mod_Auth_num","Modifier_ID","modifier_code
    }

    END { 
        for (key in Authorization_Arr) {   
            if (key != "authorization_num") { 
                print "SASH," Authorization_Arr[key] > output

                LineItems(LineItem_Arr, key, "SPLI")
                LineItems(ModifierCode_Arr, key, "SPLI_Mod")
            }
        }       
    }
'
```

Comment: Thank you glenn this was helpful. I am now dealing with the files being to large to process on my unix server. It is over 1.46 GB. The server does not have enough memory to read each line and combine into one.

Comment: Sounds like you need to import the data into a database, and write some SQL

Comment: If I only had that option my life would be easy. Now I am researching way to efficient read massive files using awk into any array. Any insights or tips?

Comment: Why don't you have that option? You could use a simple db like sqlite.